# php mail() remove CC, BCC and security

Tags: php, email

I'm new to stackoverflow and couldn't find an answer to my question which is; How do I secure my mail() code in php to prevent people from adding bcc which would ultimatly result in mass mailing? My website uses the PHP mail() service to email me when a new comment has been entered in my site. What is the best way to prevent people tampering with it, such as removing the bcc? What I have so far is:

```
function mres($input){
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    $input = stripslashes($input);
}
return mysql_real_escape_string($input);
}
$name = strip_tags(mres($_POST['name']));
$comment = strip_tags(mres($_POST['comment']));

$to = 'myself@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Website - comment';
$body = 'A new comment has been entered on the website.'."\n\n"."$name".' said:         '."\n\n"."$comment";
mail($to,$subject,$body);
```

Comment: How about not reinventing wheel and starting using phpmailer? PS: what for do you apply `mysql_real_escape_string` for the variables?

Comment: The function is asking the server if magic quotes are on or off by default. Based on the result the appropriate security measures will be activated thus preventing sql injections or similar when a comment is made.

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) use `mysql_real_escape_string` unless you're immediately using the results as part of a SQL query. (And `mail()` isn't a SQL query.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this code is followed by:

```
mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

Then it's safe, if overkill -- the only arguments to `mail()` which are vulnerable to injection are the ones that control header fields (`$to`, `$subject`, and `$additional_headers`). `strip_tags` and `mysql_real_escape_string` are both unnecessary, and the latter will make apostrophes show up as `\'` in your email.

If there's no following call to `mail()`, then it's trivially safe, because it doesn't do anything. :)

Comment: My following line is: mail($to,$subject,$body); which I accidentally omitted from the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at something like http://mailgun.com/

As it is, your mail will often end up in people's spam if you just use mail()

Comment: He's just sending himself a message here! No need for a mail service for that.

Comment: As it stands, the mail() is just emailing myself when a new comment is entered on my website. Due to low traffic volume of maybe 4-5 people per week I can afford to do this. It also allows me to check if the comment is appropriate without logging onto the website.